# Split zip archives using WinRar vs 7-Zip

Tags: zip, 7-zip, archiving, winrar

I created a split zip archive using WinRar and 7-Zip.

WinRar creates

archive.zip
archive.z01
archive.z02
....

7-Zip creates

archive.zip.001
archive.zip.002
...

With Total Commander I could enter(CTRL+PgDn) archive.zip (WinRar) and see the contents.

But I cannot enter in archive.zip.001 or any .xxx files.

Are there any differences between splitting with WinRar vs 7-Zip ?

There is definitely a difference.

Comment: Are the files 7z created shown in explorer as a zip or an unknown filetype? 7z doesn't register filetypes automatically in my experience.

Comment: 7-Zip can create .zip files also, I am not talking about .7z files

Comment: `ex.zip.001` is an .001 file in windows eyes and not a zip. Unless you have specifically registered the extension(s) it is unlikely that windows knows what it is (and apps that use the windows file type info to handle files)

Answer (score 0):

WinRar and 7-Zip are different products, so splitting will be different
between the two.

Merging in 7-Zip is done within the 7-Zip interface by
double-clicking the first file in the sequence, which will
show the split file(s) and allow the extraction.
You might also be able to open the first part by invoking 7-Zip
from the context-menu in Explorer (Windows).

For more information, see for example the detailed article
[Splitting and recombining files](https://services.ncl.ac.uk/itservice/collaboration-services/file-drop-off/splittingandrecombiningfiles/).

Comment: I was expecting some standard being applied for splitting.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard. Each product does its own thing.